# Два способа избавиться от лишних символов. А есть ли еще?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#, replace

Есть ли другие способы, получше?

Первый способ использует цикл, например убирает запятую:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i].Replace(",", string.Empty);
        }
```

Другой способ использует регулярные выражения, например так можно убрать повторяющиеся пробелы:

```
            string str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ");
```

Comment: эмм..а двух способов вам недостаточно?

Comment: надо всегда двигаться вперед

Comment: а в чем движение-то?

Comment: Эээ... А причём тут массив `arr`?

Comment: Как причем? Например:

string [] arr = new string {">", "<", ",", "(", ")"};

Comment: @pontekorvo: А причём этот массив к проблеме? Каждая строка в массиве обрабатывается по отдельности.

Comment: @VladD

Я вижу такой код. Дайте свой вариант, если считаете этот неправильным.

string [] arr = new string [] {">", "<", ",", "(", ")"};

     for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i].Replace(",", string.Empty);
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LINQ спешит на помощь!](http://ideone.com/5JI0vS)

```
string str = "qwe   rty     uiop   sdfasdfad dfafsa";
```

Убираем все пробелы:

```
str = string.Join("", str.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
// qwertyuiopsdfasdfaddfafsa
```

Убираем повторяющиеся пробелы:

```
str = string.Join("", str.Aggregate("", (s, c) => Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && s.Last() == c ? s : s + c);
// qwe rty uiop sdfasdfad dfafsa
```

Смотрим на картинку про [буханку хлеба и троллейбус](http://pit.dirty.ru/dirty/1/2010/10/11/14521-151458-41c05cd82a105c10f2ceed3d7a068440.jpg).